# Need to install C/C++ sdk appdynamics for my C++ application

Tags: c++, appdynamics

I was going through this appdynamics document page for the installation of C/C++ SDK.

[C/C++ SDK installation on Linux](https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/c-c++-sdk/install-the-c-c++-sdk-on-linux)

But since, i am doing this for the first time, i am not sure what is meant in the 3rd point.
I think i have to set the location in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable and then invoke them by typing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/appdynamics-cpp-sdk/lib
```

Can somebody explain, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you need to set "/opt/appdynamics-cpp-sdk/lib" in your "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" environment variable to use the SDK as you have posted.

Generally this is put in a script used to build your application which you are wanting to instrument.